# Extraction of N most frequent keywords per cluster in Hierarchical Clustering NLP

Tags: nlp, cluster-analysis

I want to extract n most frequent keywords per cluster from the results of Agglomerative hiearchichal clustering.

```
def agglomerative_clustering(tfidf_matrix):
    cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=95, affinity='euclidean', linkage='ward')
    cluster.fit_predict(tfidf_matrix)
    print(cluster.n_clusters_)
    labels=cluster.labels_
    print("lables is "+str(labels.shape))
    #labels = list(labels)[0]
    print("test"+str(labels))
    return labels
def tfidf(data):
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()

    vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(data)

    feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

    dense = vectors.todense()

    denselist = dense.tolist()

    df = pd.DataFrame(denselist, columns=feature_names)

    return vectors,feature_names
vectors,terms=tfidf(cleaned_documents)
labels =agglomerative_clustering(vectors.toarray())
lib['cleaned_documents'] = pd.Series(cleaned_documents)
lib['clusterAgglomerative']= pd.Series(labels)
X = pd.DataFrame(vectorized_data.toarray(),lib['cleaned_documents'])  # columns argument is optional
X['Cluster'] = labels
# Add column corresponding to cluster number
word_frequencies_by_cluster = X.groupby('Cluster').sum()
# To get sorted list for a numbered cluster, in this case 1
print("Top terms per cluster:")
print(word_frequencies_by_cluster.loc[2, :].sort_values(ascending=False))
```

The results i want each Cluster with the N most frequent keywords ?

Answer (score 0):

i tried this solution but seems it's not efficient

```
 df_lib = pd.DataFrame(lib['cleaned_documents'],lib['clusterAgglomerative'])
    print(df_lib)
    grouped_df = df_lib.groupby("clusterAgglomerative")
    grouped_lists = (grouped_df["cleaned_documents"]).agg(lambda column: ", ".join(set(column)))
    print("keywords per cluster")
    print(grouped_lists)
```